# Angular Mat-table expansion and collapse not working as intented

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am not well versed with angular, 
I got the html file as below

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="resultssummaries" multiTemplateDataRows  class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort width="100%">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Currency Code Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Currency Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="build">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Build Version </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.buildversion}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Base Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="host">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Host Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.hostAddress}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Fraction Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="tests">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef align="center"> All Tests </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.alltests}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Fraction Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="pass">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> All Pass </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.allpass}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="fails">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> All Errors </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.allfails}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="errors">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> All Errors </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" align="left"> {{resultssummaries.allerrors}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let resultssummaries" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail"
                 [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'" >
                <table mat-table [dataSource]="resultssummaries.testsummary" multiTemplateDataRows  class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort width="100%">

                    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

                    <!-- Currency Code Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="package">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> package name </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let test" align="left">{{test.packageName}}</td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- Currency Symbol Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="tests">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tests </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let test" align="left"> {{test.tests}}  </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- Base Name Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="fail">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fail </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let test" align="left"> {{ test.fail }}  </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- Fraction Symbol Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="error">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Error </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let test" align="left"> {{test.error }} </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <!-- Fraction Name Column -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="pass">
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Pass </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let test" align="left">{{test.pass}}  </td>
                    </ng-container>




                    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail1">
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let test" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
                            <div class="example-element-detail">
                                <table mat-table [dataSource]="test.testcases"   class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort width="100%">


                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left">{{testcase.date}}</td>
                                    </ng-container>

                                    <!-- Currency Symbol Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="class">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Class </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left"> {{testcase.className}}  </td>
                                    </ng-container>

                                    <!-- Base Name Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="testname">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Test Name </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left"> {{ testcase.testName }}  </td>
                                    </ng-container>


                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="rrn">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> RRN </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left"> {{testcase.rrn }} </td>
                                    </ng-container>

                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="endpoints">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> End Points </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left">{{testcase.endpoints}}  </td>
                                    </ng-container>

                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="result">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Result </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left">{{testcase.result}}  </td>
                                    </ng-container>

                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="failreason">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Result </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let testcase" align="left">{{testcase.failReason}}  </td>
                                    </ng-container>



                                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsTestcase"></tr>
                                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumnsTestcase;">
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsTestSummary"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element1; columns: displayedColumnsTestSummary;"
                        class="example-element-row"
                        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement1 === element"
                        (click)="expandedElement1 = expandedElement1 === element ? null : element">
                    </tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail1']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
        class="example-element-row"
        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
        (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>

</table>
```

my component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-resultssummary',
    templateUrl: './resultssummary.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['resultsummary.entity.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('detailExpand', [
            state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none'})),
            state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
            transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
        ]),
    ],
})
export class ResultssummaryComponent extends DataSource<any> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    currentAccount: any;
    // testsummary : ITestSummary;
    resultssummaries: IResultssummary[];
    error: any;
    success: any;
    eventSubscriber: Subscription;
    routeData: any;
    links: any;
    totalItems: any;
    queryCount: any;
    itemsPerPage: any;
    page: any;
    predicate: any;
    previousPage: any;
    reverse: any;
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'build', 'host', 'tests', 'pass', 'errors', 'fails'];
    displayedColumnsTestSummary: string[] = ['package', 'tests', 'fail', 'error', 'pass'];
    displayedColumnsTestcase: string[] = ['date', 'class', 'testname', 'rrn', 'endpoints', 'result', 'failreason'];
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IResultssummary>(this.resultssummaries);
    expandedElement: any;
    expandedElement1: any;
    constructor(
        private resultssummaryService: ResultssummaryService,
        private parseLinks: JhiParseLinks,
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private principal: Principal,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {
        super();
        this.itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.page = data.pagingParams.page;
            this.previousPage = data.pagingParams.page;
            this.reverse = data.pagingParams.ascending;
            this.predicate = data.pagingParams.predicate;
        });
    }
    isExpansionDetailRow = (i: number, row: Object) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');
    isExpansionDetailRow1 = (i: number, row: Object) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');
    connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
        const rows = [];
        this.resultssummaries.forEach(element => rows.push(element, { detailRow: true, element }));
        console.log(rows);
        return of(rows);
    }

    disconnect() { }

    loadAll() {
        this.resultssummaryService
            .query({
                page: this.page - 1,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.sort()
            })
            .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IResultssummary[]>) => this.paginateResultssummaries(res.body , res.headers),
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message),
            );
    }

    loadPage(page: number) {
        if (page !== this.previousPage) {
            this.previousPage = page;
            this.transition();
        }
    }

    transition() {
        this.router.navigate(['/resultssummary'], {
            queryParams: {
                page: this.page,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        });
        this.loadAll();
    }

    clear() {
        this.page = 0;
        this.router.navigate([
            '/resultssummary',
            {
                page: this.page,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        ]);
        this.loadAll();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAll();
        this.principal.identity().then(account => {
            this.currentAccount = account;
        });
        this.registerChangeInResultssummaries();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
    }

    trackId(index: number, item: IResultssummary) {
        return item.id;
    }

    registerChangeInResultssummaries() {
        this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('resultssummaryListModification', response => this.loadAll());
    }

    sort() {
        const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
        if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
            result.push('id');
        }
        return result;
    }
    private paginateResultssummaries(data: IResultssummary[], headers: HttpHeaders) {
        this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('link'));
        this.totalItems = parseInt(headers.get('X-Total-Count'), 10);
        this.queryCount = this.totalItems;
        this.resultssummaries = data;
        this.resultssummaries = data.map(resultsummaries =>  new Resultssummary().deserialize(resultsummaries));
        console.log(this.resultssummaries);
        /*this.testsummary = testsummary1['testsummary'][0];
         console.log(this.testsummary["tests"]);
         console.log("testsummary");
         console.log(testsummary1);
         console.log(data1); */
    }
    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }

}
```

I am able to put nested tables as i expect but when i click expand or class its not working ,for example when i click

1. the master row all the rows are expanded
2. by default all the rows are in expanded mode
3. when i click the child no expansion or collapse is happening

it will be great if you could help to fix this expand or collapse , expected

1. when master row is clicked only that row is expanded
2. on expansion of master node it should show only the immediate child
3. when the child is clicked the immediate table show
4. the same logic goes in collapse

thanks in advance

Comment: can you create a stackblitz to show the problem?